# Changing the color of a cell in a table

Tags: color

I used cellcolor to change the color of a cell in the table. But, for some strange reason, it doesnot color it completely. Why would that happen?  Below is MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,9.5pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[total={13cm,19.5cm}]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}           % include graphs/ figures  in the file
\usepackage{setspace}           % to set the line spacing in the document
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}             % to write pages in landscape environment
\usepackage{array,threeparttable}       % to add footnotes to the tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}    % to create some space between table caption and table, otherwise there was no space
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,skip=0pt}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}     % to underline the text
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\let\newfloat\relax
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{array,threeparttable,siunitx}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{grffile}            % to avoid printing the figure name (or otherwise, give figure names without spaces)
\usepackage{float}              % figures as 6 (a), 6 (b) etc.
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\raggedbottom
%\allsectionsfont{\sf

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
  \centering
  \caption{Free  (mg/100g ter) and aride compos (gy maer) in pokuls}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1.75cm}p{1.75cm}p{1.75cm}p{1.75cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{\cellcolor{blue!25}Frtion (matter)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{M\textsubscript{0}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{M\textsubscript{15}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{M\textsubscript{60}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{M\textsubscript{120}}}\tabularnewline  
    \midrule
    \textit{Esseo acids} &       &       &       &  \tabularnewline     \addlinespace
    Valine & \multicolumn{1}{c}{75} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{40} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{26} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \tabularnewline      \addlinespace
        \textit{\textbf{Total }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{11.84}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{10.24}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{9.2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{10.18}} \tabularnewline      
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
   \end{table}%    

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: @Werner   If I try it by taking it out from \textbf{}, it still gives the same solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\cellcolor` should be the first thing that appears in the cell, except when using `\multicolumn`. Below I've also provided an updated `\toprulec` and `\midrulec` which inserts a coloured separation using `\specialrule`s to make the heading more uniform:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\toprulec}{% Coloured \toprule
  \arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
  \arrayrulecolor{blue!25}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}
  \arrayrulecolor{black}
}
\newcommand{\midrulec}{% Coloured \midrule
  \arrayrulecolor{blue!25}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}
  \arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1.75cm}p{1.75cm}p{1.75cm}p{1.75cm}}
  \toprulec
  \cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{Frtion (matter)} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{M\textsubscript{0}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{M\textsubscript{15}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{M\textsubscript{60}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}\textbf{M\textsubscript{120}}} \\
  \midrulec
  \textit{Esseo acids} &       &       &       &  \\
  \addlinespace
  Valine & \multicolumn{1}{c}{75} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{40} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{26} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
  \addlinespace
  \textit{\textbf{Total }} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{11.84}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{10.24}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{9.2}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{10.18}} \\     
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Similarly, `\rowcolor` should be the first thing that appears in the row.

Comment: I get the same solution, but what I mean is that the cell that is now colored blue, is not completely blue. I see 1mm on the top and 1mm on the bottom that is uncolored. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @abhishek: See the updated answer.

Comment: Seems it like works. but if I have this table in a chapter in a thesis, where should I place this rule? in the main preamble? or close to the table - locally in a chapter?

Comment: Place the `\specialrule` definitions in your preamble and then you can use them anywhere in your document.

Comment: Works very well!!! Thanks a lot.. Have to submit my thesis this week!